# Can't use python-nmap, OSError: [Errno] 2

Tags: python, ubuntu, nmap

I am using python2 in ubuntu. Just started reading the documentation of nmap. After just using the PortScanner I get an error.

```
>>> import nmap
>>> nm = nmap.PortScanner()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    nm = nmap.PortScanner()
  File "usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nmap/nmap.py", line 118, in __init__
    p = subprocess.Popen(['nmap', '-V'], bufsize=1000, stdotut=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess,py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: have you installed nmap? what does `which nmap` say?

Comment: I have nmap installed already. which nmap returns nothing.

Comment: `which nmap` **should** return something if you really have it installed. Is it on the path? Does `nmap -V` works for you in any folder of your system?

Comment: I formerly installed it using the wget command. Now i tried the sudo apt-get and it is working fine now. I guess when installing 3rd party library sudo apt-get is most reliable?

Comment: *reliable* is not the word. What happens is that `sudo apt-get install` is a program designed to install programs in your pc. That means, updating paths, downloading 3rd party dependencies, etc. The path I think was the problem here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't have `nmap` installed in your OS. Try doing: `sudo apt-get install nmap` and test it later.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried the sudo apt-get install nmap. And now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @StavAlfi Depends on where you have it installed and if is in your path. You can add to your PATH env variable the folder where nmap is installed and should be as simple as `nmap` from the terminal.

Comment: i have installed nmap but it doesnt include to the path + the command where nmap find the nmap but still the portscanner constarctor doesnt. what is your recomandation?